# c passing pointers to functions to handle char arrays and data

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory-management

I was writing some functions that deal with strings and found out that I couldn't just pass a pointer into the function and malloc in there because it wouldn't work.

ex:

```
char* string;
void create_string(char* output, char* text) {
   len = strlen(text);
   output = (char*)calloc(1, len);
   strncpy(output, "test", len);
}
```

that's a bit convoluted but it wouldn't work anyways. I would need to pass in a pointer to a pointer like this:

```
char* string;
void create_string(char** output, char* text) {
   len = strlen(text);
   *output = (char*)calloc(1, len);
   strncpy(*output, "test", len);
}
```

and use a pointer to dereference the address. Okay, that's fine.

Next I wanted to do something similar to a function that reads a file. This function works just fine.

```
char* ru_read_file(char* data, const char* file_path) {
    FILE* fp;
    size_t buffer = 4096;
    size_t index = 0;
    int ch;

    fp = fopen(file_path, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("failed to open file: %s\n", file_path);
        return "-1\0";
    }
    printf("filepath: %s\n",file_path);

    data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer);
    while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp))) {
        data[index] = (char)ch;
        ++index;
        if (index == buffer - 1) {
            buffer = buffer * 2;
            data = realloc(data, buffer);
            if (data != NULL) {
                printf(
                    "buffer not large enough, reallocating %zu bytes to "
                    "load %s\n",
                    buffer, file_path);
            } else {
                printf("failed to realloc %zu bytes to load %s\n", buffer,
                       file_path);
            }
        }
    }
    data = realloc(data, (sizeof(char) * (index + 1)));
    data[index] = '\0';

    fclose(fp);
    return data;
}
```

the above function works and does what i expect. Next trying to pass in a pointer to a pointer as the first argument to the function I just can't wrap my head around making it work.

I though going through and updating the variables from a simple pointer to dereferencing it via a pointer would work but i am getting seg faults.

Here is the code

```
char* ru_read_file(char** data, const char* file_path) {
    FILE* fp;
    size_t buffer = 4096;
    size_t index = 0;
    int ch;

    fp = fopen(file_path, "r");
    if (fp == NULL) {
        printf("failed to open file: %s\n", file_path);
        return "-1\0";
    }
    printf("filepath: %s\n",file_path);

    data = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer);
    while (EOF != (ch = fgetc(fp))) {
        *data[index] = (char)ch;
        ++index;
        if (index == buffer - 1) {
            buffer = buffer * 2;
            *data = realloc(data, buffer);
            if (*data != NULL) {
                printf(
                    "buffer not large enough, reallocating %zu bytes to "
                    "load %s\n",
                    buffer, file_path);
            } else {
                printf("failed to realloc %zu bytes to load %s\n", buffer,
                       file_path);
            }
        }
    }
    *data = realloc(*data, (sizeof(char) * (index + 1)));
    *data[index] = '\0';

    fclose(fp);
    return *data;
}
```

how can I pass in a pointer to a pointer and use it like the working example? I would prefer to avoid reading the data then copying it to another buffer.

Comment: Do not cast the result of `malloc` & friends in C! And before you work with double pointers, you should use other mechanisms. _Functions_ have a nice feature: they can return a value.

Comment: Please don't post extensive code that works. Focus on code that doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must call `malloc` as in your second tiny example and do not cast the result of `malloc` and friends. And always check the result of `malloc`. Thus, change the line:

```
data = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer);
```

to

```
*data = malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer). 
if(*data == NULL) { // error handling
}
```

Moreover, you must derefence `data`, before indexing it because the latter operator has higher precedence. That is, replace

```
*data[index] = (char)ch;
```

with

```
(*data)[index] = (char) ch;
```

Same applies near the end, where it must be:

```
(*data)[index] = '\0';
```

Finally, you don't need this double-pointer at all, because you can just return the allocated memory as a `char *`. That is, go back to your working example, define a local variable `char *data` **instead** of a parameter and `return data;` at the end.

Comment: I have to admit that I am pretty terrible at pointers but thanks to your reply I was able to sort it out.

Comment: Thank you for the edited answer and I think I will go back to the previous example as it seems a bit cleaner after trying it with the double pointer. I really appreciate the additional info!

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
data = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer);
```

To

```
*data = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * buffer);
```

And try getting a bit more theoretical knowledge of how pointers work.

Comment: Frankly, I would not use *any* cast.